# Switch between two contents with Jquery html replace

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have **two** popups (login & register) that i want to be able to switch between them with the click event on a span.

It works for the first time but then when i want to switch from the second popup to first one, the click event doesnt trigger meaning i cant go to the first popup after i went to second.

I searched and i discovered that the click events attached to elements are lost, but still couldnt achieve a solution.

**- How can i switch between the two as many times as i want on the span click event (registerform and loginform classes) ?**

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    @include('frontoffice.login_popup')
</div>
```

The first time it loads with **login** view:

```
    <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="popup-form">
        <div class="popup_title">
            OLÁ DE NOVO, LUZINHA !
        </div>
            <p class="popupcontent"> Se ainda não pertences á familia wolistic, <br> regista-te <span class="registerform orange"> aqui </span> </p>
                {{ Form::open(array('method'=>'post','class'=> 'popup_form', 'url'=>'/customer_login')) }}
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control popupinput" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control popupinput" name="password" required>
                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group popsubmit">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">INICIAR SESSÃO</button>
                    </div>
                    <p class="text_forgotpassword"> Esqueceste a password? Nós ajudamos, clica <span class="orange"> aqui! </span> </p>
                {{Form::close()}}
        </div>
</div>
```

**Register** view:

```
<!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content" style="height: 65%">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <div class="popup-form">
          <div class="popup_title">
              JUNTA-TE À FAMILIA WOLISTIC
          </div>
              <p class="popupcontent"> Já fazes parte ? Conecta-te <span class="loginform orange"> aqui </span> </p>
                  {{ Form::open(array('method'=>'post','class'=> 'popup_form', 'url'=>'/customer_register')) }}
                          <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                              <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control popupinput" placeholder="Nome" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                              @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                  <span class="help-block">
                                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                              @endif
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                              <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control popupinput" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                              @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                  <span class="help-block">
                                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                              @endif
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                              <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control popupinput" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>

                              @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                  <span class="help-block">
                                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                              @endif
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                              <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control popupinput" placeholder="Repetir Password" name="password_confirmation" required>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="interests_list register_list">
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree"/>
                                    <label for="agree"><span></span> Li e concordo com os termos e condições </label>
                                </div>   
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="sub" name="sub"/>
                                    <label for="sub"><span></span> Quero subscrever a newsletter </label>
                                </div>   
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group popsubmit">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">REGISTAR</button>
                      </div>
                  {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".registerform").click(function(){
    $.get(
        "/registerform",
        function (data) {
            $("#myModal").html(data);
        }
    );
});

$(".loginform").click(function(){
    $.get(
        "/loginform",
        function (data) {
            $("#myModal").html(data);
        }
    ); 
});
```

**Trigger the modal:**

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("openloginpopup");
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: What code here is triggering the modals to pop up?

Comment: It looks like you're changing your html *after* you've wired up the events (and likely one of them doesn't exist at the time you set the event handlers).  Add this `alert($(".registerform,.loginform").length)` just before you set the event handlers - it should be 2, but will probably be 1.  You need to use event delegation, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements or re-wire the click handlers after loading the forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @ProEvilz added

Comment: @freedomn-m i will check

Comment: Don't vandalize your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can help you, if you press the "open" button swtich between modals if one of them are open, if not open the modal1:

**HTML**

```
<div id="openloginpopup">
    <div class="modal-content">
        open
      </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content modal1">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <div class="popup-form">
           modal1   
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content modal1">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <div class="popup-form">
           modal2   
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#openloginpopup").on('click', function(){
    if(!$('#myModal').is(':visible') && !$('#myModal2').is(':visible')){
         $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
  }else{
        if($('#myModal').is(':visible')){
        $('#myModal2').modal('show'); 
        $('#myModal').modal('hide'); 
      }else{
        $('#myModal2').modal('hide');
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
      }
  }
});

$(".modal").on('click', function(){
         $(this).modal('hide'); 
});
```

**Test link**

https://jsfiddle.net/022bca5x/12/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using Bootstrap so there is no need to use vanilla JS to control the modal and even more so when you're already using jQuery.

As per [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-methods), you can use

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');  // show the modal
$('#myModal').modal('hide');  // hide the modal
```

Try

```
$("#openloginpopup").on('click', function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

In order to open another modal from within your current modal, first hide the active one, then open the second and vice versa.

```
$("#SECOND_MODAL_BUTTON").on('click', function(){
  $('#FIRST_MODAL').modal('hide');
  $('#SECOND_MODAL').modal('show');
}
$("#FIRST_MODAL_BUTTON").on('click', function(){
  $('#SECOND_MODAL').modal('hide');
  $('#FIRST_MODAL').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution, but only this: **$("#openloginpopup").on('click', function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });** and its not working, it opens the model but its seems like it has a extra layer above and i cant click anywhere in the model neither write on the inputs, etc

Comment: It is working because the modal opens. Did you remove your own code when trying this as that could be the conflict? You can simply inspect the modal with dev tools in your browser to see what that layer is.